# Take bitmaps with camera FAST android. Snap from Surface view or convert from video?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

Hi I need to take photos from the front facing camera, as quickly as possible. I would like to turn it from 1 second + to 0.3 or less. I need to take 10-20 at a time. My clients customers need a faster solution.

Obviously the camera API will not be an ally in this. However we know that the camera can go faster. I think we can sacrifice quality to make this happen, preview looks fine in terms of overall quality. I see that we can preview the camera with a surface view, thus there is a way to get this data at 15-60 FPS. I just need a way to convert the surface view into a bitmap every few fractions of a second.

Or I could take a video, for 3 seconds and turn each frame into a bitmap. That sounds like a nightmare to code.

Any ideas on how I might go about this?

Also the application heavily crops the area of interest to about 200 x 100 pixel area. So we do not really need to worry about what is stored in memory.

Comment: With the frame size reduced to 200x100 you have a chance of making this work in real time. With full frames you'd be moving too much data through the system. Your best bet might be to direct the camera preview to an ImageReader and extract the data as YUV (assuming you can use Camera2 APIs). Extracting frames from recorded video isn't hard, but does require some effort; see e.g. http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest, and maybe the way Grafika's "continuous capture" stores a circular video (https://github.com/google/grafika).

Comment: Oh interesting. At the moment we are not using camera2. I will check with my client, I know he has some people using older versions of android. Course I could just create a special gradle flavor for the old tablets.